# Calling var array=[] within each function

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-plugins, each

I'm working on a project where I have different sets of div like heading, text, image etc..

Upon clicking I want to append input boxes for that relevant numbers of divs.

You can see working fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/UN62E/

This script does a job for me but I need improvement with this script.

This is how part of my script look like :

```
var eltofind = "heading";

if($(this).find("." + eltofind).length != 0){

    var eltoget = $(this).find("." + eltofind);

    $(eltoget).each( function(index) {
         var item = $('input.' + eltofind + ':first').clone();
        var count = (index +1);
        var getting = eltofind + "-" + count;
        item.addClass(getting);
        item.appendTo('#input');
    });
}
```

Currently I'm repeating whole script for individual sets of div. Is there a way to call all sets of divs within array? for example :

```
var eltofind = ["heading", "text", "image"]
```

& call them within each function ?

My jQuery skills aren't that good & Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a loop that loops through each value of `eltofind` and performs the appropriate actions.

```
var eltofind = ["heading", "text", "image"];

for(var i=0; i < eltofind.length; i++){
     var thisElement = eltofind[i];

    if($(this).find("." + thisElement).length != 0){

        var eltoget = $(this).find("." + thisElement);

        $(eltoget).each( function(index) {
            var item = $('input.' + thisElement + ':first').clone();
            var count = (index +1);
            var getting = thisElement + "-" + count;
            item.addClass(getting);
            item.appendTo('#input');
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make multiple selectors in jQuery

```
$(".heading, .text, .image").foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just run `$.each()` on the array an replace `eltofind` with the `el` argument:

```
var elstofind = ["heading", "text", "image"];

$.each(elstofind, function(i, el){

    if($(this).find("." + el).length != 0){
        var eltoget = $(this).find("." + el);

        $(eltoget).each(function(index) {
            var item = $('input.' + el + ':first').clone();
            var count = (index + 1);
            var getting = el + "-" + count;
            item.addClass(getting);
            item.appendTo('#input');
        });
    }

});
```